# Can't figure out amp keyframes

Tags: amp-html

Having keyframes errors @ GSC. Here what i've tried:

There was "background-position" in the codes i've changed to "opacity" then background errors gone.

But now when i put keyframes inside  it now says :

Tag 'style[amp-keyframes]', if present, must be the last child of tag 'body'.

This is the keyframes code:

```
<style amp-keyframes>
    @keyframes left_scroll{from{opacity: 1;}to{opacity: 1;}}
    @-webkit-keyframes change{0%{opacity: 1;}50%{opacity: 1;}}
    @keyframes change{0%{opacity: 1;}50%{opacity: 1;}}

    @keyframes right_scroll{from{opacity: 1;}to{opacity: 1;}}
    @-webkit-keyframes change{0%{opacity: 1;}50%{opacity: 1;}}
    @keyframes change{0%{opacity: 1;}50%{opacity: 1;}}

    @keyframes up_scroll{from{opacity: 1;}to{opacity: 1;}}
    @-webkit-keyframes change{0%{opacity: 1;}50%{opacity: 1;}}
    @keyframes change{0%{opacity: 1;}50%{opacity: 1;}}

    @keyframes down_scroll{from{opacity: 1;}to{opacity: 1;}}
    @-webkit-keyframes change{0%{opacity: 1;}50%{opacity: 1;}}
    @keyframes change{0%{opacity: 1;}50%{opacity: 1;}}
    </style>
```

When i move the keyframes codes out of < body >, errors are gone but animation stops.

Can anyone help me about this?

Thank you.

Comment: keyframes are restricted on AMP, don't use them
 https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/style_pages/#performance-recommendations:~:text=Performance%20recommendations,-These

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML should have the following structure:

```
<head>
  <style amp-custom>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <style amp-keyframes>
  ...
   </style>
<body>
```

By the way, if you use an [AMP Optimizer](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/amp-optimizer-guide/) it'll automatically generate the keyframes style block for you.